# Debian: how to create a user with root privileges (sudo)

Tags: debian, sudo, root, users

How do I create a user with root privileges in Debian? Maybe it sounds a bit silly, but I don't think I need user directories, only some rights to run services (mainly web server, mysql, etc.). I just don't want to run everything under root account.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sudo is the best way, because you can limit users to only being able to run a few commands

Giving a user rights to run everything is easy, add a line like this to /etc/sudoers:

fred ALL=(ALL) ALL

You can also limit fred to only certain stuff:
fred ALL = /usr/local/restart_www

Answer (score 2):

http://www.debianadmin.com/providing-root-privileges-for-users-using-sudo.html